# Creating jar file and include dependences classes

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a Eclipse Java project which have dependencies to an other project.

However, only some of the classes from the other classes are actually used.

Is it possible for Ant or an other tool to determine which classes are actually used and include them in the Jar?

I'm asking this because this was possible with good old JBuilder

BR,
Hugo

Comment: The classes being used can only truly be assessed at runtime and only if you can reliably run through every execution path.  This may be possible for a very simple program but will quickly become impossible as the program complexity increases.  What are you trying to achieve by including all classes in a single jar?

Comment: Well I want to have a single Jar file with all necessary classes without having to pull in a huge other project. I would say that at compile time the dependencies can be resolved. As I mentioned, this is a feature in JBuilder.

Comment: Anything but the simplest program will have both compile-time and runtime dependencies so such a mechanism is pointless.  Why are you worried about depending on another jar with a large number of classes in it?  The classloader will only load the classes as your application needs them.

Comment: I think that its much easier to maintain. I have been using this method with JBuilder for years and now I want to use Ant instead with same result.

Comment: While I agree you need to manage dependencies carefully, a jar with even a million classes in it is only one dependency and I don't think will cause you a problem.  If you only use one of those million classes then I might question whether it's worth the baggage of that dependency but nothing more.